# compare Bayesian linear regression vs standard linear regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, probability, bayesian, linear-model

**1st question,**

I recently learnt bayesian linear regression, but I'm confused that in what situation we should use bayesian linear regression, and when to use standard linear regression? What is the advantage of bayesian linear regression over standard one?

---

**2nd question,**

Also, another thing I'm confused with is that for a simple linear regression whose formula is $_=α+β_+$, why the bayesian version is as:

$_=α+β_$

$_∼\mathcal{N}(_,)$

I read from other place that $μ_$ corresponds to $_=α+β_$, what does σ correspond to? And how is the version transformation realize?

---

**3nd question,**

Last question, does $_∼\mathcal{N}(_,)$

mean that each value y $\in$
 is a normal distribution, instead of the observed data is a normal distribution?

---

Comment: $μ_$ is the mean of each $_$ and $\sigma $ it's just the variance of $_$. So $\sigma$ 'corresponds' to $y_i$ aswell.

Comment: It would be a good idea if you could post the definitions of _bayesian linear regression_ and _standard linear regression_ or the source of these terms.